# "Tag edit confirmed" notification seems to use relative or wrong URIs

Tags: bug, tags, notification-bar

While being at [networkengineering.stackexchange.com](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) I noticed that I had received a "tag edit confirmation" for "[UNIX & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)".
However when clicking on the notification I ended up at "page not found" for this URL:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/signature/info

So I guess the URL generated was incorrect or relative to the current site (obviously a bad idea).

Comment: This was fixed today - see the answer to the duplicate.